# Unexpected token in module export

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm getting the following error with a file that's part of a React app:

```
./src/utils/api.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (118:1)

  116 |         }
  117 |     }
> 118 | }
      |  ^
```

Here's the full code for the file in question:

```
import GtfsRealtimeBindings from 'mta-gtfs-realtime-bindings';
import rp from 'request-promise';

function getFeedData (sub) {
    var feedId;
    switch (sub) {
        case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case 'S':
                feedId = 1;
                break;
            case 'A': case 'C': case 'E':
                feedId = 26;
                break;
            case 'N': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'W':
                feedId = 16;
                break;
            case 'B': case 'D': case 'F': case 'M':
                feedId = 21;
                break;
            case 'L':
                feedId = 2;
                break;
            case 'G':
                feedId = 31;
                break;
    }
    rp({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=5db5e052519d17320f490738f2afe0d5&feed_id=' + feedId,
        encoding: null
    }).then((buf) => {
        const feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(buf);
        return { feed: feed };
    });

function reverseStop (sub, stop) {
    var stopIdN
    var stopIdS
    var stopData = require('./stops');
    var invalidEntries = 0;
    function filterByName (item) {
        if (item.stop_name == stop && item.stop_id.charAt(0) == sub) {
            return true;
        }
        invalidEntries++;
        return false;
    }
    var stopObjs = stopData.filter(filterByName);
    for (var i = 0; i < stopObjs.length; i++) {
        if (stopObjs[i].stop_id.charAt(stopObjs[i].stop_id.length - 1) == 'N') {
            stopIdN = stopObjs[i].stop_id;
        } else if (stopObjs[i].stop_id.charAt(stopObjs[i].stop_id.length - 1) == 'S') {
            stopIdS = stopObjs[i].stop_id;
        }
    }
    return {
        stopIdN: stopIdN,
        stopIdS: stopIdS
    };
}

module.exports = {
    isDelayN: function (sub, stop) {
        var arrivals = [];
        var delays = [];
        reverseStop(sub, stop);
        getFeedData(sub);
        (function () {
                var invalidEntries = 0;
                var feedObjs = getFeedData.feed.filter(function (feedObj) {
                    if (feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == reverseStop.stopIdN) {
                        return feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update;
                    }
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < feedObjs.length; i++) {
                    arrivals.push(feedObjs.arrival.time.low);
                    delays.push(feedObjs.arrival.delay);
                }
            })();
        var nextArrival = Math.min(...arrivals);
        var delayIndex = arrivals.findIndexOf(nextArrival);
        var delay = delays.delayIndex;
        if (delay === null || Math.ceil(delay / 60) <= 5) {
            var noDelay = Math.ceil((nextArrival - getFeedData.feed.header.timestamp.low) / 60);
            return { noDelay: noDelay };
        } else {
            var yesDelay = Math.ceil(delay / 60);
            return { yesDelay: yesDelay };
        }
    },
    isDelayS: function (sub, stop) {
        var arrivals = [];
        var delays = [];
        reverseStop(stop);
        getFeedData(sub)
            .then(function (feed) {
                var invalidEntries = 0;
                var feedObjs = feed.filter(function (feedObj) {
                    if (feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == reverseStop.stopIdS) {
                        return feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update;
                    }
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < feedObjs; i++) {
                    arrivals.push(feedObjs.arrival.time.low);
                    delays.push(feedObjs.arrival.delay);
                }
            });
        var nextArrival = Math.min(...arrivals);
        var delayInex = arrivals.findIndexOf(nextArrival);
        var delay = delays.delayIndex;
        if (delay === null || Math.ceil(delay / 60) <= 5) {
            var noDelay = Math.ceil((nextArrival - getFeedData.feed.header.timestamp.low) / 60);
            return { noDelay: noDelay };
        } else {
            var yesDelay = Math.ceil(delay / 60);
            return { yesDelay: yesDelay };
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is I'm pretty sure it's not that final bracket that's actually causing the error, but I'm not sure how to diagnose what *is* doing it. My guess is that there's something I'm not understanding properly about exporting modules? I realize a question about syntax errors isn't the best thing to post here, so thank you for bearing with me. If anyone has tips for how I can better diagnose problems like this on my own (Google wasn't helpful), I'd greatly appreciate those as well.

Comment: You have `function getFeedData` there doesn't seem to be a closing bracket for it, if you just put a bracket at the end everything will be in that function and `module.exports` won't be exposed

Comment: Wow, I am embarrassed that I didn't catch that. Gonna close this question now.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing a closing bracket in an earlier function. Let this be a lesson to me to use a linter.

Comment: Linter or an IDE ;)

Comment: @msanford not really, the question should be deleted as otherwise it'll only get closed as a typographical error.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is a great little editor with great support, not an IDE (I prefer WebStorm personally) but Code does lint in-line very effectively and _very_ quickly.

Comment: @George Ah you're right. Voted.

Comment: @msanford is right, I found this issue in Visual Studio Code, pretty much use it for any personal work I do now.

Comment: I'll check out Visual Studio Code right now.

Comment: @bkula either that or Atom, but it mostly depends on personal preference.